# how to take away the time and seconds from the database records using sqlcmd?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

`2011-12-26 00:00:00.000`
The record is from my database table . How do i remove the hours, minutes and mini seconds using **SQLCMD**?

Comment: What do you mean by eliminating hh mm and ss using SQL cmd? Are you referring to only storing month-day-year on the database side? If so and you are using SQL server 2008, just change the column to date type instead of datetime.

Comment: oh nono.. due to some policy i could not change the column type.. however i would need to take out the data and convert it to date type using sql cmd
any idea how to do it?

Comment: `sqlcmd` --> SQL Server ??? If so: which **version** of SQL Server??

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can cast to the new data type "date".

SELECT CAST(GETDATE() as date) --works only on SQL 2008

So, your query to retrieve a date part of datetime data type would look like this:

```
SELECT CAST(DateCol as date) AS "MyDate"
FROM dbo.TableWithDateTimeCol;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a `SELECT` statement to remove the time part of a date. You can use `CONVERT` to cast the date-value in a varchar to display the date in your application.

```
SELECT convert(varchar(10),datecolumn,126)
  FROM datatable
```